# How to clean fresh champignons?

Tags: cleaning, mushrooms

I bought some fresh champignons from the supermarket. What's the proper way to clean them before cooking (or rather frying) them?

Should I just wash them with cold water? Should I peel them?

Comment: I've never heard "champignons" as a name for a mushroom variety in English, and it just means mushrooms in French. I searched and Google has a dictionary definition saying they're little brown ones, while wikipedia says little *white* ones are sometimes called "champignon mushroom". So is this a particular variety? Or are you just asking [how to clean mushrooms](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/203/how-to-clean-mushrooms)?

Comment: Interesting. In Germany it's you usually call these white mushrooms champignons. I thought that's the common name for them in english, too.

Comment: @Jefromi the name is not perfectly delineated, it's usually a button mushroom, but can cover portobello and other agaricus. It's one of the most cultivated mushrooms in the world, and if there was something very special about cleaning them, I expect it would have been mentioned in the broader question. In fact, it's the first mushroom many people think about when the type is not specified.

Comment: http://static.chefkoch-cdn.de/ck.de/cms-uploads/chefkoch/467/Champignons_2.jpg - those are the kind of mushrooms I mean

Comment: That image seems to contain both white mushrooms and Crimini or "Baby Bella" mushrooms.